# Access to log files created by snakemake rules

Tags: python, glob, snakemake

is there a way to programmatically list log-files created per rule from within the Snakefile? Will I have to tap into the DAG and if yes, how?

Background: I'd like to bundle up and remove all created log-files (only cluster logs are in a separate folder; some output files have correspondingly called log files). For this I want to be specific and exclude log files that might have been created by run programs and that coincidentally match a log glob.

Are there alternatives, e.g. would parsing shellcmd_tracking files be easier?

Thanks,
Andreas

Comment: Could you add an example of a case where a file would "coincidentally match a log glob"?

Comment: Some programs create default log files (mostly ending in *log), which I would consider part of its regular output and which I don't want to bundle.

Comment: OK, so I think the solution I last suggested (expanding using "*", then passing to `glob`) should work as you want in this respect, because it does the globbing specifically on the wildcards, not on everything that is present before "log" (provided that in your explicit, snakefile-defined log files, you don't have some of them whose name consists only in a wildcard and then ".log").

Answer (score 3):

With the upcoming release 3.9.0, you can see the corresponding log files for all output files when invoking `snakemake --summary`.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to do the following

```
onsuccess:
    for rulename in dir(rules):
        the_rule = getattr(rules, rulename)
        if hasattr(the_rule, "log"):
            print(rulename, ":\t", getattr(the_rule, "log"))
```

And similarly in `onerror`.

It may be possible to put this in an expand, to generate the real log file names, if there are some wildcards in your rule's log files.

I just tested this:

```
LETTERS = ["A", "B"]
NUMS = ["1", "2"]


rule all:
    input:
        expand("combined_{letter}.txt", letter=LETTERS)

rule generate_text:
    output:
    "text_{letter}_{num}.txt"
    log:
        "text_{letter}_{num}.log"
    shell:
        """
        echo "test" > {output} 2> {log}
        """

rule combine_text:
    input:
        expand("text_{{letter}}_{num}.txt", num=NUMS)
    output:
        "combined_{letter}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        cat {input} > {output}
        """

onsuccess:
    for rulename in dir(rules):
        the_rule = getattr(rules, rulename)
        if hasattr(the_rule, "log"):
            print(rulename, ":\t", expand(getattr(the_rule, "log"), letter=LETTERS, num=NUMS))
```

And I obtain the following output at the end:

```
all :    []
combine_text :   []
generate_text :  ['text_A_1.log', 'text_B_1.log', 'text_A_2.log', 'text_B_2.log']
```

Problem is that this displays all log files potentially generated by your snakefile, not those actually generated in a particular run (if, for instance some rules don't need to be executed this time).

#### Edit: another way to expand the log file names

The `onsuccess` (or `onerror`) things could be done differently, in order to adapt to the log files actually generated:

```
import glob
onsuccess:
    for rulename in dir(rules):
        the_rule = getattr(rules, rulename)
        if hasattr(the_rule, "log"):
            print(rulename, ":\t", *[glob.glob(pattern) for pattern in expand(getattr(the_rule, "log"), letter=['*'], num=['*'])])
```

With this modification, I almost obtain the same list of filenames. The only thing that differs is the order in which they appear.

Comment: This only works if I can easily infer/expand all wildcards, correct?

Comment: If you have wildcards, something will need to be expanded at some point in order to get the real file names. But maybe the expansion could work at the shell level. Maybe expanding using "*" and then glob (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html) or doing this in the shell, outside of snakemake. I'll add an example in my answer.